# XML Self Describingness

Tags: xml, xml-validation

What do we mean when we say that XML are self-describing and when are XML doc considered as describingness.

I've read quite lot about XML Self-descrbingness here, http://docordie.blogspot.co.uk/2006/08/xml-isnt-self-describing.html but its still confusing

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is an incredibly stupid question. You read a blog that says it's meaningless to call XML self-describing, and then you ask what it means to call XML self-describing. Like the blog says, it means nothing.

Comment: what that blog is saying might be subjective, i can't afford to believe what everything from each and every blog

Comment: Well then, cite someone who uses the term as if it does mean something, rather than someone who is telling us (correctly) that it doesn't mean anything, at least in a formal sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally just used to mean the the human reader can tell what each value in the file relates to, as it is enclosed in the element name; and the position of that value in the hierarchy is equally apparent because of the rest of the elements in the XML file.

This compares with for example a CSV file, where to a human reader it is not obvious what each of the values relate to (although a header row can help with this), and which is difficult to read without a specification of the file and what the data represents.

Comment: then, does it mean that an XML doc is self describing??

Comment: It depends.  In commonly used conversation, XML documents are often described as being self describing. In a strict information science sense of the phrase, they arguably are not, see: http://workflow.healthbase.info/monographs/XML_myths_Browne.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Referenced: http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse544/04sp/papers/xml-essence.pdf

• Self-describing From the external representation one should be able to derive the corresponding internal representation.

XML is not always self-describing, since the internal format corresponding to an external XML
description depends crucially on the XML Schema that is used for validation (for instance, to tell whether data is an integer or a string).